# Bad file descriptor fgets

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to create a file to send information to another process. But when I reach the send_file function, I get -->Error in fgets():: Bad file descriptor. Can someone help me address this matter, please? I'm stuck.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void send_file(FILE *fp, int sockfd){
    char data[SIZE] = {0};
    
    if (fgets(data, SIZE, fp) == NULL){
        perror("\n -->Error in fgets():");
        }
    
    while (fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL){
        if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1){
            perror("\n -->Error in send():");
            exit(-1);
        } 
        bzero(data, SIZE);
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    int clientfd, r;    
...
    char buffer[SIZE];
    
    clientfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

...

    char *filenames = "file3.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filenames, "w");
    
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("\n -->Error creating file:");
        exit(-1);
    }
    

    char buff[30] = "This is a test text";
    fwrite(buff , 1 , sizeof(buff) , fp);
    
    
    printf("Contents: %s\n", (char *)fp);
    
    send_file(fp, clientfd);
    printf("Sent successfully.\n");
    fclose(fp);
    close(clientfd);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `fclose(fp);` - you are using `fp` after closing it.

Comment: What is `clientfd`? Please post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RaymondChen You're right, and I've just modified that. But I'm still getting that error.

Comment: Please don't change the question after it has been answered. It invalidates previous answers and will confuse future visitors to the site. (Also, you are trying to read from a stream you opened for writing.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with changing a question to improve it, as long as it does not invalidate existing answers. Changing the position of the line `fclose(fp);` did invalidate an existing answer. The other changes were ok, as they did not invalidate any existing answers. If you want to point out that making the changes pointed out in an answer does not fix the problem and you want to show your updated code, then please add that updated code to the bottom of your question with an appropriate description, instead of overwriting your previous code. That way, no answers will be invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filenames, "w");
```

Opens a file in write-only mode.

Use a read-write mode, such as `"r+"`, `"w+"`, or `"a+"`, and [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) the file appropriately to the correct position after having placed whatever data you want in it.

See [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for the semantics of each file access mode.

Alternatively, and arguably a better idea: close the file after writing to it, and reopen it in read-only mode.

---

The pattern of using `fgets` to initially check for EOF or error is flawed. If it succeeds, you will lose up to the first `sizeof data - 1` bytes of information, as the buffer is unused before the next `fgets` call, which will either overwrite it or fail.

---

```
printf("Contents: %s\n", (char *)fp);
```

It is a wild assumption that casting a `FILE *` to a `char *` will somehow yield a string.

Don't do this.